# Expression Engine channel content not showing

Tags: expressionengine

I am new to expression engine.
I have a channel name "news" and I have published some pages. In my template, I have used code as

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
  <h2>{title}<h2>
  {body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But the output is **I get the page title but the content doesn't shows up and i get `{body}` as it is on the frontend**

Can anyone help me please, where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "body" is not a valid field name?

Every "channel" has a "field group" assigned to it.  In the control panel look at the field group for your "News" channel.  Does that field group have a field with the short name "body"